# Как реализовать текстбокс, зависящий от изменяющейся переменной

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Необходимо в текстбокс транслировать информацию, приходящую с COM порта.

Пока все работает так: открывается порт и запускается функция `ReadCOM()`, бесконечно сканирующая порт, и каждый приходящий символ ею возвращается  и закидывается в строку `sRecevedChar`. Далее по нажатию кнопки вызывается `Read_button_Click` и тогда должен запускаться новый поток, как я полагаю, который будет непрерывно это все обрабатывать?

Но как мне правильно реализовать этот поток?

```
std::string COMMaster()
{
    if (sPortIsOpen == false) { _tOpenCOM(); sPortIsOpen = true; };
    string sRecevedChar = ReadCOM();
    return sRecevedChar;
}

System::Void MKDiag::MainForm::Read_button_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)      
{
    MKDiag::MainForm::ReadtextBox->Text += Convert_string_to_String(COMMaster(), ReadtextBox->Text);
    
}
```

Было бы разумно реализовать функцию в обработчике `sPortIsOpen`, куда все это запихнуть. После - запустить эту функцию, Thread-ом, но то ли нельзя функцию в методах создавать, то ли руки кривые.

ps и код конвертера, на всякий случай:

```
//конвертируем std::string в System::string^
String^ Convert_string_to_String(std::string& os, String^ s) {
    s = gcnew System::String(os.c_str());

    return s;
}
```

Comment: На C++/CLI приложения не пишут. Точка. Этот язык предназначен, по сути, для одной цели: служить _клеем_ между управляемым (C#) и нативным (C++) кодом. В общем, помощи не ждите. Мой вам совет: переходите либо на C#, либо на чистый C++. Если вас препод заставляет писать на этом языке, передайте ему от меня, что он _[цензура]_. Покажите ему этот коммент.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, уж это моя ошибка.  Хотел совместить Windows Form и известный мне хоть в какой-то мере c++.  Было бы здорово сэкономило время, если б вы меня конкретно подтолкнули по своему опыту, в чем и как тогда кодить.

Comment: @Babnook, на C#, это по большому счёту -- стандарт де-факто в мире .NET, безусловно, есть F#, но с него начинать не стоит и VB.NET, про него стоит забыть. Вообще, если Вы знаете C++ и Вам надо написать GUI-приложение, то может быть стоит воспользоваться либой/фреймворком для этого языка?

Comment: Мсье знает толк в извращениях. Пишите на шарпе. Если вам плюсы по приколу, создайте плюсовую dll, утащите туда всю математику и низкоуровневую логику, и прикрутите ее к шарпу через `[DllImport]`, а в шарпе шевелите контролы, работайте с вводом и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то у вас всё сложно, читать из COM-порта можно и на C#.

Заведите себе простейшее приложение на WPF, в окне положите

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="TextContainer"/>
```

а в code-behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GoRead();
        GoUpdate();
    }

    StringBuilder cumulatedText = new StringBuilder();
    async void GoRead()
    {
        var com = new SerialPort(portName: "COM1", baudRate: 19200, parity: Parity.None,
                                 dataBits: 8, stopBits: StopBits.One);
        com.Open();
        var stream = com.BaseStream;
        byte[] buf = new byte[32768];
        while (true)
        {
            var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            // так просто можно только с однобайтными кодировками наподобие Encoding.ASCII
            var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, actuallyRead);
            cumulatedText.Append(s);
        }
    }
    async void GoUpdate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            TextContainer.Text = cumulatedText.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Вам придётся, возможно, установить nuget-пакет [System.IO.Ports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/).

Запуск `GoRead` и `GoUpdate` можно перенести в `OnClick`, если хотите.

По идее, должно работать.

Comment: Попробую собрать на с# методом франкенштейна программу. но в вашем коде компилятор ругается на   ``` var com = new SerialPort(portName: "COM1", baudRate: 19200, parity: Parity.None,
                                 dataBits: 8, stopBits: StopBits.One); ``` Говорит, что имен Parity, StopBits не существует в текущем контексте. И что не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "SerialPort "

Comment: @Babnook: Вам по идее нужен вот этот nuget-пакет: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/

Comment: Можно то же и на WinForms, просто я не умею на нём программировать

Comment: Да, действительно, подключил библиотеку и код собрался, но выбил исключение
 System.InvalidOperationException: "Параметр BaseStream доступен, только если порт открыт."
Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]
    WpfApp1.MainWindow.GoRead() в MainWindow.xaml.cs
    [Внешний код]

Comment: А, да, ну откройте его. Сейчас допишу.

Comment: Сначала испугался кракозябров, но после настройки скорости com-порта все заработало отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: @Babnook: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Основная сложность тут не в том, чтобы запустить вашу функцию в отдельном потоке, а в том, как реализовать взаимодействие фонового потока с UI, учитывая что Winforms - однопоточный фреймворк. Для этого можно использовать BeginInvoke, но на этом проблемы не заканчиваются, так как BeginInvoke нельзя вызывать после закрытия окна. Попытка просто проверить свойство IsDisposed наталкивается на состояние гонки, ведь окно может быть закрыто одновременно с проверкой. Итоговый код с учетом этого будет выглядеть так (я слегка упростил функцию Convert_string_to_String):

```cpp
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    public:

    System::Threading::Thread^ thread;
    bool exit;
    System::Object^ sync;

    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thread=nullptr;
        exit=false;
        sync = gcnew System::Object();
    }
    
    std::string COMMaster(){
        //...
    }
    
    String^ Convert_string_to_String(std::string& os) {
        return gcnew System::String(os.c_str());    
    }

    void SetTexbox(System::String^ val){        
        textBox1->Text=val; //установка значения TextBox
    }   

    void ThreadProc(){
        auto deleg=gcnew System::Action<System::String^>(this,&MyForm::SetTexbox);

        while(1){
            //читаем строку
            auto str=COMMaster();
            System::String^ str_converted=Convert_string_to_String(str);

            System::Threading::Monitor::Enter(sync);
            try{
                if(exit)break; //поток остановлен
                this->BeginInvoke(deleg,str_converted); //устанавливаем значения TextBox
            }
            finally{
                System::Threading::Monitor::Exit(sync);
            }
        }
    }
        
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        if(thread!=nullptr)return;
        
        //запускаем поток
        auto x=gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this,&MyForm::ThreadProc);
        thread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(x);
        thread->Start();
    }
     
    System::Void MyForm_FormClosed(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^  e) {
         
         //при закрытии формы останавливаем поток
         System::Threading::Monitor::Enter(sync);
         try{
             exit=true;
         }
         finally{
             System::Threading::Monitor::Exit(sync);
         }
                
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! Для меня это уже дело принципа, все равно потом добью программу и разберусь в этом коде)